# Apple lifetime/current period call time

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how the Total minutes are calculated in the lifetime call time info? Are the minutes exact? Does this count include voicemails? Are the seconds or minutes ever rounded up or down for any reason?

Comment: Could you detail a bit about why you ask this? - Do you need it for a specific purpose? - It might be easier to answer knowing that.